# How could I transform data between several computers?

Tags: r, windows, distributed-computing

**Background:** I want to build a simple distributed environment in R, which could do some "data massive" jobs in WINDOWS. For example, to calculate "big" matrix multiplication. There seem to have varies of solutions and I worked on them for a while, but I can't fix it.

**I already tried these:** Rserve & RSclient, packages such as snow, snowfall.

I tried several ways but I can't find a proper solution to transform data between clients, and it could be a disaster if all the data transform has to through the master.

**Question: Is there any functions to deliver a matrix between every two computers as I want in a cluster?**

[image: Question]

I get an idea that maybe socket connection could work, but how can I start it gracefully? Should I have to start R script on different computers manually since there seems no SSH in the WINDOWS? I have to work on it because of my professor.

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really want to work on Linux because of RHadoop and others, but I major in mathematics and my professor prefers WINDOWS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to use  would be using  [SparkR](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) .

You will be compelled to use Spark APIs to distribute your data and there's a chance certain packages don't behave as expected but it would do the job.

A spark standalone cluster is made of a master accessible via HTTP and multiple workers. It's not the Ideal solution for resource sharing  but it's lighter than a Hadoop + spark on yarn solution.

Finally you can try [Dataiku](https://www.dataiku.com/) as it can provide such ability via notebooks, spark integration and Dataset management . The community edition is not collaborative but they provide free license to schools

Comment: Thank you, Joel. Spark do fix that problem but only work on Linux.While I want to resolve it in WINDOWS. P.S. The idea of Dataiku is genius and corporations must love it because of convenience. However, in this situation, I prefer Spark APIs and have to work on it if there are no other answers.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your comment. Having a satisfying answer her would be difficult . Maybe can you tell your professor that Microsoft reconsidered their strategy with WSL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) . BTW you can also upgrade to Windows 10 or install WSL in Windows Server for spark.

Comment: Thanks a lot.@Joel B  It sounds that WSL is a nice way.